# Looking for a bibliography style file that implements a journal's special formatting requirements

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

The following codes is in the sample file of a journal for bibliography. I need to use bibtex  for bibliography. What can I type for `\bibliographystyle{ }` to have this journal format? Thanks in advance.

```
‎\begin{thebibliography}{99}‎

‎\bibitem{1} Author‎, "‎Title of the Paper"‎, ‎\emph{Journal name}‎, ‎Vol.X‎, ‎No.X‎, ‎(200X)‎, ‎pp.XX-XX.}

‎\bibitem{2} Author‎, "‎Title of the Paper"‎, ‎\emph{Proceedings of the conference name}‎, ‎Vol.X‎, ‎No.X‎, ‎(200X)‎, ‎pp.XX-XX.‎

‎\bibitem{3} Author‎, ‎\emph{Title of the Book}‎, ‎Publisher‎, ‎(200X).

‎\bibitem{4} A.A‎. ‎Soliman‎,  ‎A numerical simulation and explicit solutions of‎
‎KdV-Burgers' and Lax's seventh-order KdV equations‎. ‎\emph{Chaos‎
‎Solitons Fractals} 29(2) (2006) 294--302.
‎\end{thebibliography}‎
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have your bib in a separate file?

Comment: @bttX Yes. My bibtex is separate.

Comment: Do you aware of  the different kind of bib style ?

Comment: @bttX No, I only know some kind of them.

Comment: Does the journal you're considering submitting your paper to provide a bibliography style file? It's rather unusual to place the `year` field in between the `number` and `pages` fields... Please advise.

Comment: @Mico The above cods are in the sample file of journal. For my article, I write a bibtex by hand. I usually use `\bibliographystyle{stylename}` and `\bibliography{bibtexname}`. I now want the style name of this journal bibliography format.

Comment: @Mico I wrote the fourth myself.

Comment: @Mico I apologize sir. My English is very blows. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can spot at least nine [yes, 9] differences between the ways bibitems 1 and 2 are formatted and the way bibitem 4 is formatted. Which formatting method applies?

Comment: @Mico 1 and 2.  Do you advise me to write bibliography by hand and forget using bibtex?

Comment: I honestly don't know of any readily available bibliography styles that would implement the formatting applied to bibitems 1 and 2. In particular, placing the `year` field in parentheses between the `number` and `pages` fields is not at all common. You may want to ask the journal's editorial staff if they can provide a bst file. If not, you may be better off simply creating the entire contents of the `thebibliography` environment by hand. It'll probably take less time than if you first run BibTeX with a "sort of not too unsuitable" bst file and then apply a lot of hand-editing to the bbl file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50862/discussion-between-fahim-b-and-mico).

Comment: Do you know the 'makebib' programme which generates a bibstyle by asking questions?

Comment: @Christian Hi, No, I do not know this program.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled the name it is called makebst and can be run by calling 'latex makebst' in a terminal window. It will ask many questions and then generate a bibstyle according to the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `makebst` tool to generate a bibstyle according to your demands. This tool is run by executing

```
latex makebst
```

in a terminal window. It will ask a number of questions and then will generate a bibstyle according to your answers. If you are not satisfied with the result you can manually edit the bibstyle but this requires some knowledge of bibtex's syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and it should help you:

```
\newpage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie} %this is to add you bib to the ToC.
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} %this si the style, ieeetr is the most used and if you want another style, try abbrv, acm, alpha, apalike, plain, siam or unsrt.
\bibliography{biblio} %this is the file of you bib ant it should be in the same directory as your main file.
```

Comment: The `ieeetr` bibliography style does *not* deliver the required format. In particular, it places the `year` field at the very end, without parentheses. The OP has stated that, at least for entries of type `@article`, the `year` field must (a) be placed between the `number` and `pages` fields and (b) be encased in parentheses. The other suggested styles -- `abbrv`, `acm`, `alpha`, `apalike`, `plain`, `siam` or `unsrt` -- suffer from similar problems.

Comment: If it is like this, you should make your own style :)

Answer (score 0):

Some journals don't have a strict rule to enforce you to use a given reference formatting.

Take a look again in the author's information, maybe you can use any format you like (as long as you provide all relevant information in each citation).